# Listview isn't supported in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, mobile

I am using jQuery v1.8.2 and jQuery UI v1.9.2, but the below code won't show correctly. Why is that, did they take out list view in the updated jQuery UI?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

The example above is taken directly from the jQuery website.

Comment: `data-role="listview"` is jQuery `mobile`, not just `jQuery`...

Comment: are you including jQuery or jQuery Mobile on your page?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Would it be acceptable to add jQuery Mobile stylesheet, while I already have none mobile jQuery references? or would that slow down the page or conflict with regular jQuery?

Comment: There is no conflict between jQuery and jQuery mobile, as the mobile is just a platform built on jQuery...you'll want to include the javascript and the css.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Okay Thanks!!! Can I choose any version for jQuery Mobile, does the version have to coincide with the versions I have listed above?

Comment: @Arian Always use the most recent versions of any script / software...they don't just release them because they like to, it's for a reason.